# Postgres' conditional trigger: performance consideration

Tags: postgresql, performance, trigger, postgresql-performance

In my DB i need to make conditional trigger, and i stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029446/postgres-insert-or-update-trigger-when-condition-old) article. Discussed in the article, there are 2 options to implement the conditions:

- Option A: condition resides in the trigger function rather than on the trigger itself
- Option B: condition resides in trigger, not in the trigger function

**Option A**

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "mytable"
    FOR EACH ROW 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE mytrigger();
```

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytrigger()
   RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin
if NEW.score > 5 then
   --code for Insert
   if  (TG_OP = 'INSERT') then
       YOUR CODE
   end if;

   --code for update
   if  (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') then
       if OLD.score <> NEW.score then
          --YOUR CODE
       end if;
   end if;
end if;
return new;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

**Option B**

Triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger1
   BEFORE INSERT ON "mytable"
   FOR EACH ROW 
   WHEN NEW.score > 5
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE mytrigger();
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger2
   BEFORE UPDATE ON "mytable"
   FOR EACH ROW 
   WHEN (NEW.score > 5 AND OLD.score <> NEW.score)
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE mytrigger();
```

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytrigger()
   RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin
  --YOUR CODE
return new;
end;
$BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

**`!`** I copied the above code from the article referred.

My question:

- Performance-wise, which one is better ?
- Is Option B better because trigger fires only when conditions met;
  while in Option A trigger will fire anyway in the first place?

Version(s) used: PostgreSQL 9.6 and afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precisely: option B is better, because it avoids the overhead of calling the trigger function for those rows where it is not necessary.